# error LNK2001 inheritance problems

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am working on a homework problem where we have to use inheritance. (I'm not very good with inheritance yet). We are to make a parent class "card_games" that has two children classes called "gofish" and "poker". We are given a template that our main has to follow, and the rest of the design is up to us.  Here is my header file: (called "classes.h")

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct cards{
  int rank;
  char suit;
};

class players{
  public:
   int points;
   int active;
   vector<cards> cardhand;
   void printhand(players *gameplayers, int person);
};

class card_games{
  protected:
    players *gameplayers;
    void player_make();
  public:
    virtual void play();
};


class poker :public card_games{
  public:
   void play();
 };


 class gofish :public card_games{
  public:
void play();
  };





void player0_play(players *gameplayers, cards *cardlist, int people);
void createdeck(cards *cardlist);
void shuffle(cards *cardlist);
void deal(cards *cardlist, int people, players *gameplayers);
int getplayers();
```

I have determined the error is something to do with my virtual call. The error specifically is:

```
cardgames_play.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall card_games::play(void)" (?play@card_games@@UAEXXZ)
```

And I believe this causes my next error of:

```
card_games.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Anyway something is wrong with my virtual void function. 
Here is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"



int main(){
  card_games *game;
  int opt;
  game = NULL;
  cout << "Poker 1, Go Fish 2" << endl;
  cin >> opt;
  if (opt == 1)
    game = new poker;
  else if (opt == 2)
    game = new gofish;
  game->play();

  return 0;
}
```

We are supposed to roughly use this template. If I understand it correctly, I am creating an instance of Card_game class called game, then assigning game to an instance of either gofish or poker. Then I dereference "game" to the "play();" function. The rest of my code, I have a

`void gofish::play(){
blah blah
}`

and a

```
void poker::play(){
blah blah
}
```

Which have the rest of my code that works.

Any help regarding this error is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. I am using visual studio 2013 on windows 8.

Comment: Either make card_games::play a pure virtual (=0 in the declaration) or give it a body ({}) in the declaration

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 1):

The method `void play();` in `card_games` does not have a body, and it is not pure virtual. Just do the change:

```
class card_games{
protected:
  players *gameplayers;
  void player_make();
 public:
  virtual void play()=0; //make it pure virtual
};
```

Comment: @user2951303,
  if this or any answer has solved your question please consider 
[accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some
reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.